# Adding a shortcut to Konsole that isn't in the "Configure Shortcuts" menu

Tags: linux, konsole

I was wondering if there was a way to add more shortcuts to Konsole. For example, I'd like to bind <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>LEFTCLICK</kbd> to open links.